# Cannot find toString

Tags: elm

I'm trying to use the `Basics.toString` function:

```
type Foo = Bar | Baz

main = text (toString Bar)
```

which, according to the Basics documentation, should be imported by default, but I'm getting a compile error:

```
I cannot find a `toString` variable:

13| main = text (toString Bar)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Basics.toString` was removed in [version 0.19](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/docs/upgrade-instructions/0.19.0.md#functions-changed):

You'll need to use one of `Debug.toString`, `String.fromInt` or `String.fromFloat`, depending on the type of `Bar`.

Comment: Note also that the `Debug` module isn't available in production builds (hence the name). If you intend to use it in production for custom types, you'll need to write your own string conversion function.